# Concrete class doesn't compile with a generic identifier

Tags: java, generics, language-lawyer

I am puzzled by this compilation error. Consider the code snippet below, `ConcreteClass1` has the following compilation error:

> Error:(16, 28) java: incompatible types:
>   java.util.Map java.lang.String,java.lang.String> cannot be converted
>   to java.util.Map java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>

Yet `ConcreteClass2` compiles successfully, simply because it extends `AbstractClass` rather than `AbstractClass<Object>`. Why is this?

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T extends Object> {

    void testGenerics(Map<String, Object> map) {
    }
}

class ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractClass<Object> {

    public void testGenerics() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        super.testGenerics(map);
    }
}

class ConcreteClass2 extends AbstractClass {

    public void testGenerics() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        super.testGenerics(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConcreteClass2` is declared as a raw type, due to omitted generic inforamtion. As per [official Raw Types tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html):

> Raw types show up in legacy code because lots of API classes (such as the Collections classes) were not generic prior to JDK 5.0. When using raw types, you essentially get pre-generics behavior

Because of above `testGenerics(Map<String, Object> map)` is interpreted as `testGenerics(Map map)` and it can be invoked with any `Map` object. All due to backward compatibility with pre Java 5 code.

You can take a look at [JLS 4.8 Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8).

Comment: Ah that explains it! Thanks very much.

Comment: "ConcreteClass2 is declared as a raw type" `ConcreteClass2` is not a raw type. It is simply a non-generic class. However, it *inherits* the raw type `AbstractClass`, and that is what causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Thats the beauty of type checks. :)

`ConcreteClass2` extends a raw `AbstractClass` and thus there is no compile time type checking. However compiler gives you a warning to not use Raw types for Parameterized classes.

When a raw type is used, the type for constructors, instance methods and non-static fields are also erased.

Comment: You mean to say that the checking is disabled for all the code in ConcreteClass2?

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra no, it is only disabled as far as inherited members of the raw super class `AbstractClass` are involved. Other generic code within `ConcreteClass2` is still checked. On the other hand, code outside of `ConcreteClass2` is also affected, if it accesses those members.

Comment: That's true. Using a raw `AbstractClass` will result in type erasure for complete class including its constructors, instance methods and non-static fields.

Comment: Is it really a warning? I see `Information:19/09/2018 09:57 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 4 s 930 ms` And an information message `Information:java: ...\ConcreteClass2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`